# Transaction silently rolled back

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

```
@Modifying     
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE FROM BusinessTransaction bt WHERE bt.userId.id=:id")     
void deleteByUserId(Long id);
```

For this query I am getting the following error:

> Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

In this query `userID` is an object of `User` class joined and mapped with `BusinessTransaction` class, so in the `where` condition I am trying to fetch id of user from `userId.id` and it should be same as `:id` variable.

Can anyone please help me resolve this error?

Comment: There is no difference between your two queries. How are you calling your query?

Comment: @yogeshyogi - I removed the second half of your question because it appeared to be an exact copy/paste of the first half of your question. If that is not what you intended, you can [edit] the question to correct/improve it. See also [ask] for more guidance.